# Как сделать ЧПУ с помощью htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url

Есть страницы вида `site.com/?page=2`.

Как с помощью *htaccess* сделать `site.com/page/2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteCond нужен, чтобы не было бесконечного цикла. Нужный код редиректа можно подставить в конце RewriteRule после пробела, например `[R=301]`. Если планируете сохранить другие элементы query, то подставьте туда же `[R=301, QSA]`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !page=
RewriteRule page/(.*)$ /?page=$1
```

Comment: не работает чего-то

Comment: а как не работает? я у себя на сервере посмотрел, работает :)

Comment: Извиняюсь, свою отладку не убрал :)

Comment: )) я так и сделал) я не совсем уж новичок)

Comment: И как не работает? у меня запускает  с `_GET["page"] 1`

Comment: аа не стоп, если прописать вручную /page/2 То работает, но я думал что это будет делатся автоматически

Comment: а ты хочешь наоборот? сейчас на входе `/page/2`  редиректаются на `/?page=2`

Comment: всё, настроил) спасибо большое)

Comment: обращайтесь, если что :) можено даже отметить ответ :)

Comment: я бы отметил, если не сейчас то позже, но вспомнил бы точно)

Comment: Спасибо! Вобщем-то, это я так по привычке :)